# Web Publish password not the same as my Azure admin password?

Tags: asp.net, azure

For whatever reason when I published my server for the first time to Azure some really long password was generated for me that for whatever reason I didn't think would be an issue.

Apparently I need this to publish to my server.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xal1D.png

It does not match my Azure server admin password which I can easily change from the management portal. Is there a way to see what this password is and/or change it?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

> Is there a way to see what this password is and/or change it?

Click the link in `Azure portal -> Your Website -> Dashboard -> Quick glance -> Download the publish profile`.

[image: See Azure deployment password]

Download the file and your publishing password should be there in plain text in form `userPWD="7vasdfa...."`.

If you want to reset that you can click the link `Azure portal -> Your Website -> Dashboard -> Quick glance -> Reset your publish profile credentials`.

Comment: just FYI, the password which is included in the Publish Profile which you download is **not** your Deployment Credentials password. It is auto generated one. This is well described in the Kudu WIki.

Comment: With "deployment" I meant "publish". Changed text to be more clear about that.

Comment: My UI looks a little different. In case it helps anyone find it: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d810dpbynlxh26x/azureUI.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 46):

For the same solution as Kaspars Ozols presented but for the new Azure Portal you can go to App Services, open the App Service in question and click the "Get publishing profile"

[image]

Comment: Does not work in Safari FYI. Works in other browsers. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/15555174-downloading-publish-profile-in-new-portal-doesn-t

Answer (score 4):

Updating thread since it is now 9/2018.

Goto Azure Portal -> Dashboard -> App Service (that you are deploying to) -> Get publish profile (in the top middle of browser)

Once you have the file downloaded, look for the userPWD arg.

Answer (score -2):

No it is not the same. Reason is pretty clear - security concern!

My "Azure Admin Password" is to manage all my Azure Resources. While when I publish a web site to Azure I would expect to have some other credentials, that do not have to all my azure services.

What you see there is a `Deployment Credential`. This is best explained in the [Wiki Page for the Kudu Project](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials). Note that Azure Web Sites run [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu).

Comment: I don't think this answer is exact because it talks about `Deployment Credentials` but OP uses `WebDeploy` and clearly states that this password was auto generated. So OP is talking about `Site-level credentials (aka Publish Profile Credentials)` not `User-level credentials (aka Deployment Credentials)`.